# How can I combine an encypted PDF with a non encrypted PDF?

Tags: pdf, encryption, command-line

My OS is Ubuntu. I tried using `pdfunite foo.pdf bar.pdf foobar.pdf`, but was prompted with the exception:

`Unimplemented Feature: Could not merge encrypted files ('bar.pdf')`

The stats of the encrypted file:

- Author: US Government IRS
- Producer: Text® 5.4.2 ©2000-2012 1T3XT BVBA
  (AGPL-version)
- Creator: eServices TDS
- Format: PDF-1.4